# how can I use a state as an array of objects

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-state, react-typescript

I have recently started learning React TypeScript, and I am trying to make a Bowling Score application. I thought about state (I don't know much about states, just started learning it)  so I can put an array of object inside the state and use it which will make the values in each frame changes when I press the roll buttons. This is my code :

```
  type frame = {
    leftScore: any;
    rightScore: any;
    lastFrameScore: any;
    totalScore: any;
}
const game = new Game();
const [score , setScore] = useState<frame[]>([]);

function App() {
    setScore({score : game.score}); // got error here

    return (

        <div className='container'>
            <div className="RollsContainer">
                <h1>hi </h1>
                {[...Array(11)].map((e , i) =>
                    <button key={i} onClick={() => handleRolls(i)}>{i}</button>
                )
                }
            </div>
            <div className="frameContainer">


                {[...Array(10)].map((e , i) =>

                    <Frame
                        framenbr={i + 1}
                        leftbox={score[i + 1].leftScore}
                        rightbox={game.score[i].rightScore}
                        lastbox={game.score[i].lastFrameScore}
                        totalScore={game.score[i].totalScore}
                        key={i + 1}/>)
                }

            </div>


        </div>
    )

}
```

this is game class:

```
export class Game {
    curentFrame: number;
    roll: any;
    score: frame[] = [];

    constructor() {
        this.curentFrame = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            this.score[i] = {
                leftScore : '' ,
                rightScore : '' ,
                lastFrameScore : '' ,
                totalScore : '' ,
            };
        }


    }
}
```

I got this error

```
Error:(15, 15) TS2345: Argument of type '{ score: frame[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<frame[]>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'score' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction<frame[]>'.
```

I don't know if this is right or wrong I tried so many solutions but did not work

Answer (score 0):

You are setting score like this.setState instead useState hook, so change your setScore like below and also try putting intial object array with frame type instead of empty array.

```
...
const initialObj = {
                     leftScore : '' ,
                     rightScore : '' ,
                     lastFrameScore : '' ,
                     totalScore : '' ,
                   }
const [score , setScore] = useState<frame[]>([initialObj]);
...
setScore(prev => [...prev, game.score]);
```

Comment: `push` mutates the original array. You should never mutate the state. Instead do `setScore(prev => [...prev, game.score])`

Comment: Ya it's right. updated thanks

Comment: Thank you for both of answord but It did not work I got `Error:(15, 14) TS2345: Argument of type '(prev: frame[]) => (frame | frame[])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<frame[]>'.
  Type '(prev: frame[]) => (frame | frame[])[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: frame[]) => frame[]'.
    Type '(frame | frame[])[]' is not assignable to type 'frame[]'.
      Type 'frame | frame[]' is not assignable to type 'frame'.
        Type 'frame[]' is missing the following properties from type 'frame': leftScore, rightScore, lastFrameScore, totalScore`

Comment: try with updated code by proving initial object array instead of empty array which is causing type error I think